# how to find the remote branch of local branch

Tags: java, git, jgit

I created local branch 12345 from origin/master that relevant to gerrit

How I can find the remote name refs/for/master for the local branch 12345

The input is the branch name refs/heads/12345 or part of the string

I calculated it branch Name in :

```
   public String getCurrentBranch() throws GitException {
        try {
            Ref headRef;
            headRef = repository.getRef(Constants.HEAD);
            return Repository.shortenRefName(headRef.getLeaf().getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new GitException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

How I Can find the result of the remote  refs/for/master to res/heads/12345 ?

Do I need to do it from the config ?

Comment: I am afraid, I don't understand what the desired outcome should be, can you rephrase your question more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've cross-tagged this as both [git](/questions/tagged/git) and [jgit](/questions/tagged/jgit) (and then also [java](/questions/tagged/java), which seems completely inappropriate here, but I'll leave that to others) and I can only give a pure-[git](/questions/tagged/git) answer, which may be unhelpful.

In Git, a branch—by which I mean the branch *name*, not the [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068543/what-exactly-do-we-mean-by-branch)—can have at most one *upstream* set.  When a branch has an upstream set, the branch is said to *track* the upstream.  This upstream is normally a remote-tracking branch name, e.g., `master` may track `origin/master`.  The name `origin/master` is a *remote-tracking branch*, so we say that "branch `master` tracks remote-tracking branch `origin/master`": this has far too many occurrences of the words "branch" and "tracks", each with a different meaning, but we're kind of stuck with it.

A branch that tracks another branch need not track (i.e., have as an upstream) a remote-tracking branch at all.  For instance, local branch `feature/zorg` might track local branch `develop`.  The only things that having an upstream does for you are to automate more of `fetch`, `merge`, and `rebase` (and hence `pull` which is just `fetch` followed by one of the other two), and give you more information when running `git branch -v` (or `-vv`, etc) and `git status`.  Of course, these are fairly significant, and hence are a reason to set an upstream.

The *upstream*—the name of the other branch that the given branch is tracking—is set in two parts: a *remote*, which is the name of a remote if the upstream is a remote-tracking branch, and a *branch* (name).  If the remote is set to `.`, the branch is tracking another local branch.

These two parts may be obtained individually with `git config` or `git config --get` (both do the same thing):

```
$ git config --get branch.master.remote
origin
$ git config --get branch.master.merge
refs/heads/master
```

Note that the second part has not undergone the mapping(s) specified by the `fetch` rule for the given remote:

```
$ git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Since this mapping says that `refs/heads/*` becomes `refs/remotes/origin/*`, we can determine that *our* name for the remote-tracking branch that corresponds to `refs/heads/master` on remote `origin` is in fact `refs/remotes/origin/master`.  (Of course, this mapping is pretty standard and some software might just assume it, but it's better practice to actually *do* the mapping using the setting(s) for `remotes.origin.fetch`.  There may be more than one, hence the `--get-all` here.)

Again, if the `remote` part is set to `.`, the upstream is actually a local branch, and no mapping should be applied to the `merge` part.

In shell script, then, you could do something like:

```
branch="${1:-master}"
has_upstream=true
remote="$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote)" || has_upstream=false
merge="$(git config --get branch.$branch.merge)" || has_upstream=false
if ! $has_upstream; then
    echo "branch $branch has no upstream"
else
    case "$remote" in
        .) echo "branch $branch tracks local branch $merge";;
        *) echo "branch $branch tracks $merge on $remote";;
    esac
fi
```

This does not help with the mapping, if you'd like to check the remote-tracking branch (you may of course need to run `git fetch` to update it), but you can get *that* using `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Note that you need to strip `refs/remotes/` from the result when it is a remote-tracking branch, if you want to use the short form.  Of course if the upstream is a local branch, the full name will begin with `refs/heads/` rather than `refs/remotes/`.  If you want the current branch's upstream, a simple `@{u}` suffices; the `name@{u}` syntax allows you to find other branches' upstream names.

The `@{u}` suffix makes `rev-parse` fail if there is no configured upstream:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name target@{u}
fatal: no upstream configured for branch 'target'
```

which offers another way to tell if an upstream is configured.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be late, but here you go:

```
private static Ref findCurrentBranch(Git git) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
    String currentBranch = git.getRepository().getFullBranch();

    return git.branchList()
            .setListMode(ListBranchCommand.ListMode.ALL)
            .call()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getName().equals(currentBranch))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}

private static Optional<Ref> findRemoteBranch(Git git, Ref branch) throws GitAPIException {
    Optional<Ref> remoteBranch = git.branchList()
            .setListMode(ListBranchCommand.ListMode.REMOTE)
            .call()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getObjectId().getName().equals(branch.getObjectId().getName()))
            .findFirst();

    return remoteBranch;
}
```